# Why do canvas functions createRadialGradient & addStopColor render inconsistent gradients with respect to their SVG counterparts?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, html5-canvas, webapi

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
c.width = 200;
c.height = 200;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(c);
var offx = 47.50, offy = 41.05;
cx.moveTo(15.30 + offx,57.05 + offy);
offx += 15.30;
offy += 57.05;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(7.00 + offx,-3.55 + offy,7.00 + offx,-8.50 + offy);
offx += 7.00;
offy += -8.50;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(0.00 + offx,-5.05 + offy,-7.00 + offx,-8.55 + offy);
offx += -7.00;
offy += -8.55;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(-7.00 + offx,-3.50 + offy,-16.80 + offx,-3.50 + offy);
offx += -16.80;
offy += -3.50;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(-9.85 + offx,0.00 + offy,-16.85 + offx,3.50 + offy);
offx += -16.85;
offy += 3.50;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(-7.00 + offx,3.50 + offy,-7.00 + offx,8.55 + offy);
offx += -7.00;
offy += 8.55;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(0.00 + offx,4.95 + offy,7.00 + offx,8.50 + offy);
offx += 7.00;
offy += 8.50;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(7.00 + offx,3.50 + offy,16.85 + offx,3.50 + offy);
offx += 16.85;
offy += 3.50;
cx.quadraticCurveTo(9.80 + offx,0.00 + offy,16.80 + offx,-3.50 + offy);
offx += 16.80;
offy += -3.50;
var g = cx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
g.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1.000)');
g.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.502)');
cx.fillStyle = g;
cx.fill();
```

The corresponding SVG can be opened in the same browser & will demonstrate the shading works correctly:

```html
<svg width="94.95" height="101.60" viewBox="-47.50 -41.05 94.95 101.60" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="shape_56" style="stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;">
  <radialGradient cx="0.500" cy="0.500" r="1.000" fx="0.000" fy="0.000" id="gradient_003099AC" gradientTransform="matrix(1.000,0.000,0.000,1.000,0.000,0.000)">
    <stop style="stop-color: #000; stop-opacity: 1.000;" offset="0" />
    <stop style="stop-color: #000; stop-opacity: 0.502;" offset="1" />
  </radialGradient>
  <path style="stroke: none; stroke-opacity: 0.000; stroke-width: 0.00; fill: url(#gradient_003099AC); fill-opacity: 1.000;" d="M 15.30,57.05 q 7.00,-3.55 7.00,-8.50 q 0.00,-5.05 -7.00,-8.55 q -7.00,-3.50 -16.80,-3.50 q -9.85,0.00 -16.85,3.50 q -7.00,3.50 -7.00,8.55 q 0.00,4.95 7.00,8.50 q 7.00,3.50 16.85,3.50 q 9.80,0.00 16.80,-3.50"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Same issue as [Canvas - RGBA in gradient not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918737/canvas-rgba-in-gradient-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug no. The default value for [<radialGradient>'s `gradientUnits`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits#radialgradient) attribute is `objectBoundingBox`.

There, `r="0.5"` represents half the size of the shape being filled.

In the canvas version, the units you pass to `createRadialGradient` are the coordinates on the canvas system. So there `0.5` means half a pixel.

Ps: there is no quick way in the canvas API to have this `objectBoundingBox` behavior, the easiest is to calculate yourself the correct coordinates.

Comment: It's explained in the link I gave. Conceptually, first they assume BBox is square, then they define the rings as circles based on that square, finally they stretch these rings to ellipses in the same direction the assumed square is stretched to meet the actual rectangular BBox.

Comment: You can scale the canvas's transform matrix after you defined your path, this will set it only for the gradient. So you'd have to find the BBox of your path, define it and then do something like `cx.fillStyle = g; cx.setTransform( bbox.width, 0, 0, bbox.height, bbox.left, bbox.top ); cx.fill()`. https://jsfiddle.net/bg25knhf/ (I got the BBox from eye-sight, I'll let you find how to calculate it)